# Unknown encoding similar to base64

Tags: encoding, base64

I have looked at a variety of questions regarding strings with an encoding similar to base64, but none of them helped me with this string:

```
khvVM0gpOpAP/mUxEa90mrkiNGJ1vBPgygZJMuMrNcY=
```

It is from an HTTP request. The header name is `X-Request-Token`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This is a token header, which correspond to a unique identifier to this formular.
See [this page](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-web-toolkit/Zg8teY6gjHU/9w4QLO05-0AJ)